# Wedges in Blender

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and 3D modelling in general. I've been trying to make a wedge in what feels like hours now with no result (using the knife tool) Anyone who can help me out and tell me how you make a simple wedge?

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBVrF.png) what you want? If not, edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Start with a cube, then go to Edit Mode.
Select two opposing vertices, merge them with Alt M/at Centre.
Pick the other pair of vertices on that face and merge them too.
Is that the shape you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very quick way to do it:
make a cube, select one corner edge, and hit delete.  In the delete drop-down, press "dissolve edges."  You now have a wedge!